# HTML page to PDF in Python?

Tags: python, html, pdf-generation

Is there a library available to convert a HTML page (text, images, layout elements etc. ) to a PDF file.

I have an HTML page with figures, text and tables with numbers etc. which I want my clients to be able to download as PDF. How do I do this with Python?

Answer (score 3):

Not too familiar with python, and prince is nice if you are willing to shell out the cash.  There is this http://github.com/antialize/wkhtmltopdf that uses webkit.  It is a simple command line utility that you can call and it will honor html+css.  As far as I know, it is the only free tool to do so well.  There is a ruby gem for it http://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit, not that it helps you but might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are the `reportlab` and `html2pdf` modules, but for best results I'd probably try calling `Prince` externally (http://www.princexml.com/doc/6.0/python/) .

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard of xhtml2pdf/pisa?

It has the ability to work as a python module or as a separate command line utility.

You can use the documentation here to get started:
http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/doc/pisa-en.html